# Encode a double in a char array in c#

Tags: c#

I want to encode a double into a char array (so it can be sent on a socket) 
I am a novice at C# so I naively tried this

```
 double latitude = 100.20;
 char[] xx = new char[20];
 xx = latitude.ToString().ToCharArray();
```

But this just gives a string representation and I need the value to be encoded into the array.
Can someone please point me in the right direction

Comment: What do you mean by "encoded"? I.E., what's your desired output?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "I need the value to be encoded into the array"? Does it definitely need to be text rather than binary anyway? (Binary data is what goes down sockets, after all...)

Comment: You can use BitConverter to convert your double [to bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=netframework-4.8#System_BitConverter_GetBytes_System_Double_) and from bytes [to double](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.todouble?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It all depends on the requirements and the expectations of the receiver. You have to format and/or encode the data so that the receiving side correctly understands the data you are sending. Whether you send it over a socket or with a homing pigeon does not really matter in this regard. You vaguely pondering about char arrays does not really help us understanding your _actual_ problem of how to send the data so the receiver will understand it correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading raw bytes one would use

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(latitude)
```

Note that the type is a `byte` array, rather than a `char` array. Chars in C# are two bytes in size, as they represent unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `xx` is a char array. You can check it by this way:

```
            double d = 100.2;
            char[] xx = d.ToString().ToCharArray();
            Console.WriteLine($" Type of xxx is {xx.GetType()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Length : {xx.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Items : ");
            foreach (char c in xx)
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

It seems that you mean a byte array in your case. Try this: `Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(xx);`